# Identify personal comments python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

So I'm currently trying to identify comments wherein a person is talking about him/her-self.  I'm using Spacy's POS tagging and have chosen to use 'nsubj', 'poss' and 'nsubjpass' as indicator tags for first person.  Ofcourse, this fails with more complex sentences such as

"Yeah, mostly delusion. Occasionally laughter"
or "Brain down dragging in the dirt, parasites and grubs all around the folds. Whisper whisper, will it all go away?"

```
Yeah intj
mostly advmod
delusions ROOT
. punct
Occasional amod
voices ROOT
. punct
```

Would appreciate some help to identify such sentences as being personal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Textacy: Something on this line

list(textacy.extract.semistructured_statements(doc, 'I', cue='be'))